# Drop all columns in a table if their names follow a specific pattern in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

I have a table from which I need to drop multiple columns that follow a pattern. 
Say columns names in my table are (A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3) and I need to drop all columns that starts with a B (B1, B2, B3). I was able to pull those in a separate query but still not able to run a drop statement on the output. 
I really appreciate the help. Please note that I am not allowed to deploy scripts with cursors. So pure SQL is preferable.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you allowed to use DynamicSQL?

Comment: I would prefer not to but yes I am allowed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this. Use `Dynamic SQL` to generate **Drop scripts** of columns which is following specific pattern

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @sql += ' Alter table ' + TABLE_NAME + ' DROP COLUMN ' + COLUMN_NAME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'
       AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SchemaName'
       AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'DatabaseName'
       AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'B%'

--print @sql
EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: I'd add a condition in the `WHERE` for `TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schemaname'`.  Otherwise you if you have the same table under a different schema you're in trouble.  Might be a good idea to make sure you're in the correct database too.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg - Yes bro thats right. Updated the answer.

Comment: This works, even though it is a two-step solution. Would it be possible to add an automatic execution of the generated scripts?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'll need to construct the statement dynamically, then execute it. You can do this form within T-SQL. This solution assumes you want to drop all columns simultaneously.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = REPLACE('ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable DROP COLUMN $c;', '$c', 
    REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(
        (
            SELECT QUOTENAME(Name) + ','
            FROM sys.columns 
            WHERE columns.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable')
            AND columns.name LIKE 'B%'
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    ), 1, 1, '')));
PRINT @sql; -- show what we've produced 
-- EXEC(@sql);  -- uncomment to execute
```

The only magic here is the use of `FOR XML` plus some funky string manipulation to remove the final comma and produce the list like `DROP COLUMN` wants to have it. This is a useful technique in general.